# displacement component in jsf form when error validation css

Tags: css, forms, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, panel

I have this xhtml page :

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./template_admin.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="tohead">
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">


                <p:panel header="Edition d'une commande"  style="height: 490px;margin:auto;" id="panel"  >
                    <p:messages id="msgs"/>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="float:left;" columnClasses="column" cellpadding="5">

                        <h:outputLabel  for="idd" value="Id : " />   
                        <p:inputText  disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.id}" id="idd" required="true" requiredMessage="veuillez saisir un nom" label="Nom"  />  
                        <p:message for="idd" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="dteenvoi" value="Date d'envoi : " />  
                        <p:inputText disabled="true" id="dteenvoi" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.dateEnvoi}" required="true" requiredMessage="veuillez saisir un prénom" label="Prénom" />  
                        <p:message for="dteenvoi" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="division" value="Date de livraison recommandée : " />  
                        <p:inputText disabled="true"  id="division" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.dateLivraisonRecommande}" />  
                        <p:message for="division" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="poste" value="Nombre de page : " />  
                        <p:inputText id="poste" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.nbrePage}" />  
                        <p:message for="poste" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Nombre d'exemplaire : " />  
                        <p:inputText id="email" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.nbreExemplaire}" />
                        <p:message for="email" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="autres" value="Type d'impression : " />  
                        <p:inputText id="autres" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.typeImpression}"  />  
                        <p:message for="autres" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="identifiant" value="Observation : " />  
                        <p:inputTextarea id="identifiant" disabled="true" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.observation}" required="true" validator="#{addUserController.validateIdentifiant}" requiredMessage="veuillez saisir un identifiant" label="Identifiant" />  
                        <p:message for="identifiant" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="dec" value="Decision : " />  
                        <p:selectOneMenu  id="dec" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision}" >  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.decisions}" />  
                            <p:ajax update="etat calen gridContainer :myform:alors" listener="#{editCommandController.decisionlistener()}" event="change" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  
                        <p:message for="dec" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="etat" value="Etat : " />  
                        <p:selectOneMenu  id="etat" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.etat}" disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée' or editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'en attente'}" >  
                            <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.etats}" />   
                        </p:selectOneMenu>  
                        <p:message for="etat" display="icon"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="calen" value="Date de Livraison réelle: *" />
                        <p:calendar  label="Date de Livraison reelle" id="calen" showOn="button" disabled="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'rejettée' or editCommandController.myCom.decision eq 'en attente'}" effect="slide" value="#{editCommandController.myCom.dateLivraisonReelle}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" >
                        </p:calendar>  
                        <p:message for="calen" id="msgSurname4" display="icon"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>  

                    <p:outputPanel id="gridContainer" style="margin-left: 150px;" layoyut="block" >
                        <h:panelGrid id="alors"   rendered="#{editCommandController.myCom.decision ne 'rejettée' and editCommandController.myCom.decision ne 'en attente'}" >
                            <h:outputText value="ci dessous la liste des papiers ayant un stock (>=) à la quantité demandé" style="font-size: 0.7em;margin-bottom: -3px;" />
                            <p:dataTable  id="cars" style="width: 80px;margin-top: -6px;" var="car" value="#{editCommandController.pdm}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
                                         selection="#{editCommandController.selectedPapier}" selectionMode="single" >  

                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":myform:jesuis :myform:jesuis1 :myform:jesuis2" />  

                                <f:facet name="header">  
                                    RadioButton Based Selection  
                                </f:facet>                    

                                <p:column headerText="libelle"  >  
                                    #{car.libelle}  
                                </p:column>  

                                <p:column headerText="format"  >  
                                    #{car.format}  
                                </p:column>  

                                <p:column headerText="stock"   >  
                                    #{car.stock}  
                                </p:column>  

                            </p:dataTable>  


                            <h:outputText  id="jesuis" value="vous avez choisi le papier : #{editCommandController.selectedPapier.libelle}"  />
                            <h:outputText id="jesuis1" value="la quantité nécéssaire : #{editCommandController.myCom.nbreExemplaire*editCommandController.myCom.nbrePage}" />
                            <h:outputText id="jesuis2" value="la quantité réstante en Stock : #{editCommandController.selectedPapier.stock - (editCommandController.myCom.nbreExemplaire*editCommandController.myCom.nbrePage)}" />
                            <span id="relief" ></span>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="margin-top: 15px;">  
                                <h:outputLabel value="Reliure :" for="city" />
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="Reliure" required="true" value="#{editCommandController.choixReliure}">  
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="choisir reliure" itemValue="" />  
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{editCommandController.libelleReliures}" />  
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{editCommandController.vclistener()}" />  
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:outputPanel>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="clear:left;" >
                        <p:commandButton value="Editer" ajax="false" action="#{editCommandController.updateCommand()}" update="panel" ></p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton value="Annuler"  immediate="true" action="commandesUser" ajax="false" ></p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </p:panel>  

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

when I run my application and I open this page : 
I have it like this
[image]

but when I click on edit button and if there are a erro in validation : 
I have the form like this : 
[image]

I don't know the cause of this displacement components

do you have any idea how to resolve this problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave it a fixed height.

```
<p:panel header="Edition d'une commande" style="height:490px;margin:auto;" id="panel">
```

Remove it to make it as high as its contents.

```
<p:panel header="Edition d'une commande" style="margin:auto;" id="panel">
```